# Does the NWS/NOAA provide a Beach Safety conditions API?

Tags: api, weather, noaa

I see that the National Weather Service has a couple of pages with current [Green/Yellow/Red flag conditions](https://www.weather.gov/media/tae/RipCurrentFlags.pdf) for beaches:

https://www.weather.gov/greatlakes/beachhazards

But where does that data come from? I can see it's an embedded ArcGIS map, but do they provide beach conditions as an API somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

NOAA doesn't provide a Beach Safety conditions API